# Errors when trying to call methods of a class in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, class, methods, console

So I'm trying to help some students with a project as I am a Supplement Instructor for the class, which I have not taken. I have experience in Java, C++, C#, etc., but not much with Objective C and it's truly throwing me for a loop

This is my console including the error it gives me.
2015-10-14 13:32:41.806 Triangle[10548:303] Enter a, b, and c.
3.1 1.23 2.0
2015-10-14 13:32:47.913 Triangle[10548:303] +[Triangle print]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1000022c8
2015-10-14 13:32:47.914 Triangle[10548:303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[Triangle print]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1000022c8'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ad2d25c **exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff86f85e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ad3002d +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ac8b272 ___forwarding_** + 1010
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ac8adf8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Triangle                            0x0000000100001a98 main + 200
    6   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8bda65fd start + 1
    7   ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Here are my three files
Triangle.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Triangle : NSObject

@property double a;
@property double b;
@property double c;
+ (id) initWithA:(double)a andB: (double)b andC: (double)c;
- (double) perimeter;
- (double) area;
- (void) print;

@end
```

Triangle.m

```
#import "Triangle.h"

static double _a, _b, _c;

@implementation Triangle

+ (id) initWithA:(double)a andB:(double)b andC:(double)c
{
    if (self == [Triangle class]) {
        _a = a;
        _b = b;
        _c = c;
    }
    return self;
}

- (double) perimeter
{
    return _a + _b + _c;
}

- (double) area
{
    double s = (_a + _b + _c)/2;
    return sqrt(s*(s - _a)*(s - _b)*(s - _c));
}

- (void) print
{
    NSLog(@"a = %f b = %f c = %f", _a, _b, _c);
}

@end
```

main.m

```
#import "Triangle.h"
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    double a, b, c;
    NSLog(@"Enter a, b, and c.");
    scanf("%lf" "%lf" "%lf", &a, &b, &c);
    Triangle* tri = [[Triangle alloc] init];
    tri = [Triangle initWithA:a andB:b andC:c];
    [tri print];
    NSLog(@"Area = %f Perimeter = %f", [tri area], [tri perimeter]);
    return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have mixed metaphors somewhat.

`init` methods should be instance methods rather than class methods.

The caller would then create a Triangle in a single statement with:

```
Triangle *tri = [[Triangle alloc] initWithA:a andB:b andC:c];
```

The implementation should be something like:

```
- (instancetype) initWithA:(double)a andB:(double)b andC:(double)c
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _a = a;
        _b = b;
        _c = c;
    }
    return self;
}
```

EDIT ---
There is a fairly common pattern of returning an instance from a class method but it doesn't use `init`.  Typically, that would be done as:

```
+ (instancetype)triangleWithA:(double)a b:(double)b c:(double)c {
    return [[self alloc] initWithA:a andB:b andC:c];
}
```

(Also "and" as part of a method signature is usually annoying.  :) )

Comment: this is what I wanted to put as an answer :)

Comment: When I try changing it to what you said, I get an error that says Cannot assign to 'self' in a class method at the the self = [super init]; line. Also I get an error when initializing tri when I do it your way. I replied to a similar comment about it below.

Comment: Like I said, "`init` methods should be instance methods rather than class methods."  (Change the plus signs to minuses.)

Comment: The professor wants it as a + though. I assume I'm taking the whole wrong approach when it comes to making a class method then? I tried looking online and I've had trouble finding something that explains it well and a lot of examples seem to be broken up and don't show me how to work with initializing more than one variable (the andB andC piece).

Comment: If the professor wants '+' on an `init`, I hope the professor finds a more suitable line of work **soon**.  There are lots of examples within Apple's own SDK of `init` methods that take multiple parameters.  Look at UIViewController's `- initWithNibName:bundle:`, for example.